# Python savefig of large matrix uses ridiculous amount of memory

Tags: python, memory, matplotlib

I was playing with the MovieLens10M Dataset and wanted to get some visualizations.. in short, my code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M= np.random.randint(2, size=(70000,10000))
plt.figure(figsize = (2,1), dpi=5)
plt.imshow(M,interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis('off')

plt.savefig('pic.png',dpi=5)
```

The matrix takes about 6GB in memory, but the required memory explodes as soon as savefig is invoked- it goes up to 20GB until I stop the script.. Setting dpi=5 and the figure size so small were only desperate attempts to get some output..

Are there possibilities to tell the savefig function that it doesnt have to make such a fuzz or do I really need to, e.g., sample??

Comment: That is a *ridiculously* large array to plot. matplotlib was certainly never designed to imshow an array that big, and even if it could it would be pointless since your array contains about *two orders of magnitude* more elements than there are pixels in a 4K monitor. You will lose almost nothing by downsampling your array to every 10th row/column before plotting it - if there was any structure that fine then you almost certainly wouldn't be able to see it at full scale on your monitor anyway. Otherwise, view a cropped region of it at a time.

Comment: If your goal is just to save the array as a `.png` then you would be better off using `plt.imsave` to write it directly to disk rather than trying to plot it first. Even then, I'm not sure what you would do with a `.png` image that big.